# Почему не работает этот пример?

Tags: c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main (void)
{
    int handle;
    char buf[11] = "0123456789";

    /* создать текстовый файл из 10 байт */
    handle = open("d:\\1.txt", O_CREAT);
    write(handle, buf, strlen(buf));

    /* обрезать файл до 5 байт */
    chsize(handle, 5);
    close(handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не расскажите, что не так?

Comment: Просто обожаю такие вопросы: "Почему не работает"

Сразу рука тянется к запыленному телепатическому шлему ...


Comment: Или к минусомёту.

Answer (score 2):

> Name
>
> open, creat - open and possibly create a file or device
>
> Synopsis
>
> `#include <sys/types.h>`
> `#include <sys/stat.h>`
> `#include <fcntl.h>`
> `int open(const char *pathname, int flags);`
> `int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);`
> `int creat(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);`
> ....
> The parameter flags must include one of the following access modes: `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, or `O_RDWR`. These request opening the file read-only, write-only, or read/write, respectively.

У меня с gcc 4.5.0 (mingw) пример работал с `O_CREAT` | `O_WRONLY`. С одним O_CREAT файл создавался нулевой длины соответсвенно.

Answer (score -1):

А разве не так?

```
сhar buf[11] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

Comment: Без разницы.

Comment: Да нет, не без разницы. :) strlen и {0, дают интересный эффект.

Comment: Естественно, подразумевалось, при условии замены strlen на размер буфера. Но глобально пример не изменится.